# Converse for Lidskii's Theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a compact operator on a Hilbert space. Let $(\lambda_n)$ be the sequence of its eigenvalues repeated with their algebraic multiplicity. The Theorem of Lidskii says that if $T$ is trace class, then the sum $\sum_n\lambda_n$ converges absolutely and equals the trace of $T$. Now my question is for the converse: suppose that $\sum_n|\lambda_n|<\infty$. Does it follow that $T$ is trace class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is not true. Take for example the following operator on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$. $$T(e_{2n})=0,T(e_{2n+1})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e_{2n}$$One can check easily that $T^2=0$, so all $\lambda_n=0$ but $\mu_{2n}=0,\;\mu_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{n}$. Hence $T$ is compact but not trace class.

Comment: Outch! Should have seen that. I was too much focussed on the non-zero-eigenvalues...